# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error al hacer un merge con hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy realizando un actualizar a la tabla empleado(idEmpleado,nombreEmpleado,telefono) de mi `BD`, usando hibernate para las operaciones *CRUD* pero cuando ejecuto el método en el `main` me devuelve el siguiente error, agradecería me pudieran ayudar.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
    at com.ejemplo.hibernate.dao.EmpleadoDaoImpl.actualizar(EmpleadoDaoImpl.java:68)
    at com.ejemplo.hibernate.service.EmpleadoServiceImpl.actualizar(EmpleadoServiceImpl.java:30)
    at com.ejemplo.hibernate.controller.Ejecucion.main(Ejecucion.java:30)


 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

public Empleado buscarporId(int id) {
        Empleado emp = null;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            emp = session.find(Empleado.class, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return emp;
    }

@Override
    public void actualizar(Empleado emp) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
        try {
            session.merge(emp);//update
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmpleadoService empleadoService = new EmpleadoServiceImpl();

        Empleado find= empleadoService.buscarporId(2);
        find.setNombreEmpleado("Ronaldinho");
        empleadoService.actualizar(find);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No has empezado la transacción propiamente, prueba a sustituir

```
Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
```

por

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
```

Comment: muchas gracias, estimado.